# Projecting a point on a Freefrom surface

Tags: c++, projections, nurbs

My first issue is getting a set of planes and a set of points as input, an find the projection of the those points on the nearest plane.

That was pretty easy, where i just calculate the normal of the plan and do some linear algebra to find the best plane to project  onto.

Now i do not have just normal planes, i have a set of freeform surfaces, like $\textit{Bspline}$ and $\textit{Nurbs}$ and i have to project my given points on those surfaces. i Struggle to find the  minimum distance between the point and the surface.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What accuracy do you need? Could you convert the surfaces to a set of planar polygons? That might be easier to work with. (Or it might tank performance because now you have hundreds of polygons instead of 1 surface. I'm just thinking out loud.)

Comment: well i am new in this field, can you maybe give me some hints about about how to convert any arbitrary surface to  a set of polygon. coz i dont think using the control point directly would really help